# Laravel: Find exact match, case sensitive

Tags: sql, laravel, vue.js

This code works but it is not sensitive to case/capitalization.

```
    public function search(){

        if ($search = \Request::get('q')) {
            $patrons = Patron::where(function($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('barcode','=',"$search")

            })->paginate(20);
        }else{
            $patrons = Patron::latest()->paginate(5);
        }

        return $patrons;
    }
```

Example

> Searching for 'banana123' should NOT be equal to 'BaNaNa123' and should return 0.

How can we make the search exact match? Thank you.

Comment: r u using mysql?

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL through PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use BINARY

```php
use DB;
...
public function search(){
    if ($search = \Request::get('q')) {
        $patrons = Patron::where(function($query) use ($search){
            $query->whereRaw("BINARY `barcode` = '$search'");
            // or
            // $query->where(DB::raw("BINARY `barcode`), $search);
        })->paginate(20);
    }else{
        $patrons = Patron::latest()->paginate(5);
    }

    return $patrons;
}
```

Also if you are using one where and not chaining it to other conditions you don't need to use function inside where. you can simply write:

```php
use DB;
...
public function search(){
    if ($search = \Request::get('q')) {
        $patrons = Patron::where(DB::raw("BINARY `barcode`"), $search)->paginate(20);
    }else{
        $patrons = Patron::latest()->paginate(5);
    }

    return $patrons;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your time. It works!